# A definition to 3-tuple ( $(a, b, c): = \{ \{a\},\, \{a, b\},\, \{a, b, c\} \} $) and other problems

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've found these problems but I can't find neather a counterexample nor a way to proof them:

1) ¿There exist sets $A,\, B,\,  C$ such as $A\cap{B}\neq{\emptyset},\, A\cap{C}= \emptyset $ and $ (A\cap{B})\backslash C = \emptyset$?

2) Proof that:

2.1) $ \backslash $ cannot be expresed in terms of  $\cup{} $ and $\cap{} $

2.2) $\cup{} $ cannot be expresed in terms of $\cap{} $ and $\backslash $

3) Consider the next possible definition of ordered pair: $(a,\, b):=\{ \{a,\, \emptyset\},\,  \{b,\, \emptyset\} \} $. ¿Does this definition satisfy the  contidtion $(a,\, b)=(c,\, d) \Longleftrightarrow{} a=c\ $  and  $\ b=d $?

4) If it is tried to generalize the definition of ordered pair to a 3-ordered-tuple  $(a,\, b,\, c) $ as $(a,  b,  c): = \{ \{a\},\,  \{a, b\},\,   \{a, b, c\} \} $ it will be not succed, because the idea of «ordered» fails. Proof this fact.

In (1), my conjecture is that those sets don't exist, 'cause a necesary contidition to $ (A\cap{B})\backslash C = \emptyset$ happen is that $A\cap B \subseteq C$ (with $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$), but this means that $A\cap C\neq \emptyset$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to write this formally.

For (3) I think that with $a=1$ and $b=0$ is enough to show that $(1, 0)=\{ \{1,\emptyset\}, \{0, \emptyset\}\}=\{\{0,\emptyset\}, \{1, \emptyset\}\}=(0, 1) $ but $1\neq 0$, and therefore the condition is not satisfied; however I'm not sure.

Finally, In (2) and (4), I don't even know how begin.

Comment: In (4) you might begin by looking for a counterexample. It's easy to see that you can recover $a$, $b$, and $c$ from $(a,b,c)$ if the elements $a,b,c$ are all different, or if they are all the same, so look at cases where they have two different values. Under the proposed definition of ordered triple, what sets do $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, and $(1,2,2)$ turn out to be?

Comment: In (1), $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ means that there is some element $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in B.$ Is $x\in C$? Consider two cases, and show that each case leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I already fixed it.

Comment: 2.2 is contrary to DeMorgan's law.